# Different methods to install Bitdefender Antivirus Scanner for Unices

Tags: software-installation

When I was searching for information about the Bitdefender Scanner for Unices I found two different methods for installing the scanner in Ubuntu 12.04. [Number 1](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-bitdefender-via-ppa-ubuntu) and [Number 2](http://connectwww.com/how-to-install-bitdefender-antivirus-scanner-for-unices-on-ubuntu-12-04/2359/)

Which should I use? What advantages does the different methods have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to use the first one, the repo method. That repo is maintained by bitdefender, it is easier and you will be notified if newer versions are available.

But I also advise you to check how old are the bitdefender packages in [that repo](http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/pool/non-free/b/). More than 3 year old versions doesn't look good. (Most likely the virus definitions are fresh though.) Looks like Bitdefender is not really into this business on Linux.

My personal advice is that if you need a virus scanner for linux, use ClamAV or ClamTk.